# Read file sometimes returning empty string

Tags: python, file

I have the following code:

```
my_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
excludes_file_path = os.path.join(my_dir, 'excludes.txt')

with open(excludes_file_path, 'r') as f:
    print('start pos', f.tell())
    excludeLines = [line.rstrip('\n') for line in f]
print('excludes', excludeLines)
```

When I run this code I get an alternating print of:

```
start pos: 0
excludes: ['string', 'string']

start pos: 0
excludes: []
```

I have read about the file being at the end sometimes when it is read before. I am trying to prevent that with the 'r' option in the opening of the file. Also the start pos is always at 0. I have tried to do `f.seek(0)` as well. But it will still alternate. The only way I always get the first outcome is when I remove the rstrip. I need the trailing new line stripped from the strings though. What is happening?

Comment: @mad_ `for line in f` iterates over the file by calling `readline`.

Comment: Can you provide *exact* code that demonstrates the problem? I don't see how you can get the claimed output. Either you aren't resetting the file handle (in which case `start_pos` would be greater than 0) or you are, in which case `excludes` should not be empty.

Comment: Show your input also... because your code as is won't do want you claim it does.

Comment: I have added the file path code

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a hard time reproducing the error you're getting. However, if all you're trying to do is get the file into a list where each line is a separate entry, then you can use `f.read().splitlines()` and can drop the list comprehension. This will remove the "\n".

Comment: I try to prevent readlines because of this:

http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.com/2013/06/readlines-considered-silly.html

Comment: Sorry, just edited to give a nice way to remove the "\n" with builtin operations, and no readlines!

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. Later on I was opening the file again for writing and closed it later on. Somehow the same code run twice messes that up. Thanks for all the help to the others.